401 Unauthorized. Laravel Sanctum. Cookie based authentication
I am trying to authenticate with the http only cookies. My front end is VUE 3 and backend is laravel.
I am successfuly logging in. My login functions is
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $credentials = $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required'
            ]);

            if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Invalid email or password',
                ], 401);
            }

            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            $user_resource = new UserResource($user);

            $token = $user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken;

            //$cookie = Cookie::make('access_token', $token, 180, '/', null, false, true, false, 'Strict');
            $cookie = Cookie::make('access_token', $token, 18000, null, null, false, true, true, 'Lax');


            // Return a successful JSON response with the user data and token
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User Logged In Successfully',
                'user' => $user_resource,
                'token' => $token
            ])->withCookie($cookie);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'A server error occurred. Please try again.'
            ], 500);
        }
    }

after that when i try to send request for users list with the cookies on the header i got the 401 error. 
Hosts file on my machine:
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1   server.sample.com
127.0.0.1   client.sample.com

the config/cors.php file:

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://client.sample.com:5173'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,  // Allow sending credentials (cookies)


config/session.php
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

config/sanctum.php

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

and .env file is
SESSION_DOMAIN=sample.com

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS ="sample.com"

and my api.php file is as follows:
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
}); 

also cookies:

What am i not seeing here?
SESSION_DOMAIN=.sample.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="http://client.sample.com:5173,http://server.sample.com:8000,server.sample.com,client.sample.com,http://client.sample.com,http://server.sample.com"
tried this one with no use. I have no idea what is wrong.
Also this is the request i am sending      `      const response =  axios.get(apiUrl + '/users', {
    withCredentials: true,

  });`


As it is an API, cookies do not care, you need to send the token and vue to store it, and every time it sends something, you have to send the token back, but not as a cookie. You have to send an Authorization header with the value Bearer {TOKEN} (replace {TOKEN} with the token)

@matiaslauriti the OP is trying to implement 'airlock' which is cookie based, while you are talking about API keys. Both are supported by Sanctum

To use sanctum, you must understand the difference between "API token authentication" and "SPA authentication". Which one are you using?

@TUPKAP I did not understand that part, my bad!
